# Weblogic JMS consumer - using XPath in selector with quotes

Tags: xpath, jms, weblogic

I'm trying to subscribe to WebLogic JMS messages using selector containing XPath. In WebLogic, it's achieved using 'JMS_BEA_SELECT' function. Something like this:

```
 session.createConsumer(topic, "JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '/Parent/text()') = '123'");
```

This seem to work, but what if I need to use quotes in the expression? For example, how do I subscribe when my XPath expression is something like this (which is the only way to have namespace-insensitive query):

```
 "//*[local-name()='Parent']/text()";
```

How do I specify single quotes of the above expression when I call `createConsumer(topic, "WHAT GOES HERE?")`?

Note that all the following variants didn't work (throw invalid expression exceptions):

- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=\\\"Parent\\\"]/text()') = '123'"`
- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=\\\'Parent\\\']/text()') = '123'"`
- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=\"Parent\"]/text()') = '123'"`
- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=\'Parent\']/text()') = '123'"`

**EDIT:**

Following the suggestion by @better_use_mkstemp, I tried using `&quot;` and `&apos;` encoding. It doesn't throw exceptions, but it also **doesn't select the message**.

To be clear on the problem I'm having, below is the actual message I have in the queue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ServiceResponseNotification xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/services/types">
    <ServiceResponse>
        <IsFailure>true</IsFailure>
    </ServiceResponse>
    <ServiceRequestId>2642697</ServiceRequestId>
</ServiceResponseNotification>
```

And here's the code fragment:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "...");
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(ht);

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("jms/TestConnectionFactory");
Destination dest = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup("jms/TestJMSQueue");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

String sel = "JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=&apos;ServiceResponseNotification&apos;]/*[local-name()=&apos;ServiceRequestId&apos;]/text()') = '2642697'"; 
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(dest, sel);
Message m = consumer.receive(1);
if (m != null) {
    System.out.println(((TextMessage)m).getText());
} else {
    System.out.println("No messages");
}
```

The above code returns `null`, no matter if I'm encoding quotes as `&quot;` or as `&apos;`. The XPath above, when applied over this XML using regular XPath testing code - works fine.

Another option I thought of - is to use double single-quotes, which, for example, are suggested when using ApacheMQ (I didn't try it, but this doc says it's OK: http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html). Both below variants don't throw exceptions, but also don't select the message:

- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=''Parent'']/text()') = '123'"`
- `"JMS_BEA_SELECT('xpath', '//*[local-name()=''Parent'']/text()') = '123'"`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

First your syntax for the variants you tried doesn't match your example that works... is it `=` or `==`? Is it `'123'")` or `'123')"` ?

Second there is a fair amount of info out there about this, from the w3 xpath docs:

"To avoid a quotation mark in an expression being interpreted by the XML
processor as terminating the attribute value the quotation mark can be
entered as a character reference (`&quot;` or `&apos;`)"

Reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/178536-how-do-i-escape-single-tick-marks-xpath-queries

http://userscripts.org/topics/127322

http://kushalm.com/the-perils-of-xpath-expressions-specifically-escaping-quotes

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typos in my examples and I tried to use XML encoding for quotes. It doesn't throw expression exceptions now, but it also doesn't select my message. I updated the question with relevant stuff. Could you please look into it? Thanks a lot.